# Problem regarding finitely generated group

Tags: abstract-algebra

which of the following statement are  necessarily true ?

$1.$ There exist a finitely generated group containing some element of infinite order

$2.$There exist an infinite group  which is not  finitely generated  but all whose element  have finite order

$3.$ There exist a finitely generated infinite group  no element  of which have infinite order

My atempt : For $1$ , I could not able to find the counterexample

I think $ 2,3$ are true

For $2$. take  $\mathbb{Q}$

For $3$. take $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: When you say $\mathbb Z$, presumably you mean the additive group?  But then, what is the order of $1$?

Comment: There is only one element of finite order in $\Bbb Q$, and that is $0$.

Comment: Should say:  $\#3$ is a terribly difficult problem.  For years it was thought that there was no such group, but a non-trivial example was found.  This is known as the [Burnside Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_problem).

Comment: @lulu order of $1$ will be $2$ since $1^2=1$

Comment: u mean it is a research problem for $3$ @lulu  actually this question asked in our quiz test

Comment: No...as you are speaking of the additive group of integers, $1+1=2\neq 0$.

Comment: I doubt anybody gave you $\#3$ as a quiz problem. If so, they made a mistake.  It's a famously hard problem.  But are you sure they didn't add "abelian" or something?

Comment: oh sorry @lulu  i think order $1$ will be infinite  in additive group of integer

Comment: Every element, except $0$, has infinite order in $\mathbb Z$.  So...that settles $\#1$!

Comment: ya,they didn't add abelian @lulu

Comment: Finding a counter-example to a "there exists" statement.... Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first quest, You can look at $(\Bbb Z, +)$ it is finitely generated but every element is of infinite order.

For the second quest, consider $\overline{\Bbb Z _{p}}$, which is the algebraic closure of $\Bbb Z_p$. each element in this group is of finite order but it is not a finitely generated group.

For the third quest, consider the group $\Bbb Z^{2}$ which finitely generated, the answer is that there finitely generated infinite $p$-groups. which every element is of order of some power of $p$.